# RxCocoa map optional error in Swift4 with 'Cannot convert value of type 'String?'

Tags: swift, swift4, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

In working through the tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa

using Xcode 9.3 and Swift4

There is the code:

```
private func setupTextChangeHandling() {
  let creditCardValid = creditCardNumberTextField
    .rx
    .text //1
    .throttle(throttleInterval, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) //2
    .map { self.validate(cardText: $0) } //3

  creditCardValid
    .subscribe(onNext: { self.creditCardNumberTextField.valid = $0 }) //4
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag) //5
}
```

This is giving an error on the map() call on the $0 parameter:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'String'

```
func validate(cardText: String) -> Bool
```

Is the declaration of the called function inside the map closure.

In looking at the Apple docs, the map (optional) should pass an unwrapped variable in as the parameter so $0 should already be unwrapped and I don't see any notes on it being deprecated or changed.

Not quite sure what is wrong here.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

`RxSwift`'s map won't unwrap for you (neither does Swift's btw; you can remove `nil`s from an array with `compactMap`).

`RxSwift` has a nice little convenience operator that allows to convert `nil` to an empty string and avoid the optional:
`textField.rx.text.orEmpty`

Side note: `addDisposableTo` is deprecated; you should use `disposed(by:)`

Comment: Actually, Swift has two map() functions, one for Arrays and one for optionals and the Apple docs say it will unwrap it for you:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map